# field_image_cache missing from all content types

Tags: 6, entities

I've had a strange thing happen to a Drupal 6 site. All images are missing from the site. Looking at the Edit screen for a node shows that the ability to edit and upload an image for any node is missing.

Further checking the content types shows that under 'Manage Field' the 'Image' field [field_image_cache] has be removed for every content type.

As far as i can see all the correct modules are still enabled.

Anyone got any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Just thought I would update this one, just in case anyone else has a similar problem.

Turns out that the database was erroring and running out of disk space. Which meant the queries couldn't be completed. This ended up corrupting the database and I had to restore from a backup.

Once the restore completed all images and ability to Edit them returned to the site.

Hope that helps.